# RN - Typescript - Component Wrapper

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've got a component that conditionally wraps its contents with TouchableOpacity or View depending whether one of the props is present (onPress callback).

```
const Wrapper = onPress ? TouchableOpacity : View;
```

Then the return block of the component is:

```
<Wrapper style={style} onPress={onPress}>
      {children}
  </Wrapper>
```

Typescript complains about Wrapper not having any

> TS2604: JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call
> signatures.

Do I need to annotate it. If so, how? I tried:

```
const Wrapper: ReactNode = ....
const Wrapper: TouchableOpacity | View = ...
```

Clearly that's not the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Wrapper` this way, you need the `onPress` variable before you could evaluate the ternary expression.

```js
const Wrapper = onPress ? TouchableOpacity : View;
```

To get it from props, you will have to create a component and then you can access the `onPress` on the `props` object.

```
function Wrapper(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  if (props.onPress) {
    return <TouchableOpacity {...props} />
  }
  return <View {...props} />
}
```